# Como recorrer un array que me devuelve una petición ajax en JAVASCRIPT y PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

estoy tratando de recorrer un array mediante javascript pero no logro hacerlo, esto es lo que tengo al momento:

```
$(".tablas").on("click", ".btnPedirmasdatos", function () {
    var codigoVenta = $(this).attr("valorCodVenta");
    $.ajax({

        url: "ajax/ventasValida.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            "codigoVenta": codigoVenta
        },
        success: function (respuesta) {

            console.log(respuesta);

        }

    });

});
```

y me devuelve esto en consola:

> productos: "[{"id":"737","descripcion":"Pomada para labios
>   paloma","cantidad":"8","stock":"79","precio":"7","total":"56"},{"id":"475","descripcion":"CONTRA
>   CANASTA
>   ","cantidad":"1","stock":"89","precio":"30","total":"30"},{"id":"727","descripcion":"Cople
>   Union
>   3/8","cantidad":"1","stock":"64","precio":"10","total":"10"},{"id":"733","descripcion":"Cincho
>   de Nylon 3.5X250mm
>   50Pza.","cantidad":"1","stock":"67","precio":"13.8","total":"13.8"},{"id":"530315269","descripcion":"pepsiCola","cantidad":"6","stock":"NaN","precio":"5","total":"30"},{"id":"1843819268","descripcion":"mandado
>   Bueno","cantidad":"8","stock":"NaN","precio":"9","total":"72"},{"id":"728","descripcion":"Tuerca
>   Izquierda","cantidad":"1","stock":"53","precio":"8.8","total":"8.8"},{"id":"691","descripcion":"TAPON
>   PVC 1 1/4 MACHO
>   ROSCADA","cantidad":"4","stock":"96","precio":"9.23","total":"36.92"}]"

Mi php que devuelve la respuesta:

```
class AjaxVentas{

    /*=============================================
    EDITAR CLIENTE
    =============================================*/ 

    public $codigoVenta;

    public function ajaxDetalleVentaCliente(){

        $valorID = $this->codigoVenta;

        $respuesta = ControladorVentas::ctrMostrarListaProductsVenta($valorID);
        if ($respuesta != "error") {

                        echo json_encode($respuesta);


        }else{
            echo '{
                    "data":[]
                }';
        } 


    }

}
```

y este es mi módelo:

```
static public function mdlMostrarDetalleVentaId($tablaaBO, $valorID) {



        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT productos FROM $tablaaBO WHERE codigo = '$valorID'");

        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {

            return $stmt->fetch();
        } else {
            return "error";
        }


        $stmt->close();

        $stmt = null;
    }
```

mi controlador:

```
static public function ctrMostrarListaProductsVenta($valorID) {

        $tablaaBO = "ventas";

        $respuesta = ModeloVentas::mdlMostrarDetalleVentaId($tablaaBO, $valorID);

        return $respuesta;
    }
```

Comment: Puedes publicar tu php? Es que esta algo extraña esa respuesta ya que no la envia entre `{ }` si no solo producto asi!

Comment: listo @Bryro mira asi hago el proceso.

Comment: Intenta con console.log(respues.productos[0])

Comment: No me aparece nada amigo solo este corchete [ , que estará pasando?

Comment: haz un var_dump($respuesta) en vez del  json_encode y muestalo aqui, porque hay algo raro. Además la estructura devuelta por el if y el else de ajaxDetalleVentaCliente creo que son diferentes, te dará problemas al tratar la respuesta.

Comment: As esto while($row =$stmt->fetch()){ $data[] = array( "id" => $row["id"], los otros datos y fuera del while return $data;

Comment: por cierto, en el ajax llamas a ctrMostrarListaProductsVenta() pero nos has puesto el código de mdlMostrarDetalleVentaId()

Comment: con console.log(respues.productos[0])  te aparece un corchete porque lo que has recibido es un string y no un json

Comment: O $data = array; while($r = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ $data[] = $r; y luego del while return $data;

Comment: @Bryro publique una respuesta con lo que sale de var_dump y al hacer lo que mencionas del while, me devuelve el id null

Comment: @Bryro y con $data = array; while($r = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ $data[] = $r; y luego del while return $data; me devuelve un error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_assoc()

Comment: Es asi perdon $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )

Comment: cierto, ahora me sale asi:
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["productos"]=> string(858) "[{"id":"737","descripcion":"Pomada para labios paloma","cantidad":"8","stock":"79","precio":"7","total":"56"},{"id":"475","descripcion":"CONTRA CANASTA ","cantidad":"1","stock":"89","precio":"30","total":"30"},{"id":"727","descripcion":"Cople Union 3/8","cantidad":"1","stock":"64","precio":"10","total":"10"},{"id":"733","descripcion":"Cincho de Nylon 3.5X250mm 50Pza.","cantidad":"1","stock":"67","precio":"13.8","total":"13.8"},{"id":"530315269","descripcion":"pepsiCola"...

Comment: Ahora si lo recorres como la respuesta abajo saludos!

Comment: @Bryro ya hice lo de recorrerlo con $(respuesta.productos).each(function(indice,elemento){
       console.log(indice, elemento);
       // aqui haces la comparacion
       if (elemento.id > 900) {
      
       }
    });

pero no me muestra aun nada en consola

Comment: Hay un id 900? En tu json? Valida con otro numero a ver si no intenta hacer un cast to int

Answer (score 0):

cambia el `console.log(respuesta);` por:

```
    $(respuesta.productos).each(function(indice,elemento){
       console.log(indice, elemento);
       // aqui haces la comparacion
       if (elemento.id > 900) {
       ....
       }
    });
```

y el `each` irá iterando por todos los elementos.

Más informacion en la documentacion oficial https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Hola amigo ya lo hice y me aparece esto en consola:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [{"id":"737","descripcion":"Pomada para labios paloma","cantidad":"8","stock":"79","precio":"7","total":"56"},{"id":"475","descripcion":"CONTRA CANASTA ","cantidad":"1","stock":"89","precio":"30","total":"30"},{"id":"727","descripcion":"Cople Union 3/8","cantidad":"1","stock":"64","precio":"10","total":"10"}....

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer cuando recorra el array es comparar si el ID es mayor a 900

Comment: asegurate que recibes es un JSON válido, puedes usar esta herramienta web https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: una vez recibas los datos correctamente puedes hacer la comparación con if (v.id > 900).....  porque ahora mismo parece que te llega un texto que no es parseable como JSON

Comment: si de hecho me aparece en la validacion del JSON que no es válido y no entiendo por que sea eso!! asi lo tengo guardado en la base de datos

Comment: vale, pues la cuestión es con el json no con la iteración... ¿puede poner un volcado  de ControladorVentas::ctrMostrarListaProductsVenta($valorID) ?